# malloc gives weird allocation memory address

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` to compile my code and using `QEMU` as the simulator. Everything worked fine before until I tried to call the `safe_malloc` inside the `send_no_wait`. If I call `safe_malloc` here, the function `send_no_wait` will return to a wrong address, and the program will crash within several assembly instructions. The `safe_malloc` function works elsewhere, my thought is that maybe the memory is corrupted somehow, because when I comment some functions which need memory allocation before `send_no_wait`, the `send_no_wait` works again...

This is the memory address it allocates in the case that the `safe_malloc` will lead to a crash.

```
(gdb) p m
$5 = (msg *) 0x10501 <_vfiprintf_r+1796>
(gdb) p *m
$6 = {pData = 0x10519 <_vfiprintf_r+1820> "U", Status = 1, pBlock = 0x1b440, 
  pPrevious = 0xddef90, pNext = 0x2d0e92a} // pPrevious and pNext should point to 0x0
```

This is the memory address it allocates in the case that the `safe_malloc` will not lead to a crash(I comment some functions which need memory allocation).

```
(gdb) p m
$1 = (msg *) 0x1b460
(gdb) p *m
$2 = {pData = 0x1b478 "U", Status = 1, pBlock = 0x1b428, pPrevious = 0x0, pNext = 0x0}
```

What does that `<_vfiprintf_r+1796>` mean? Is there something wrong with this piece of allocated memory here?

```
exception send_no_wait(mailbox *mBox, void *pData) {
  volatile uint first_execution = TRUE;
  SaveContext();
  if (first_execution == TRUE) {
    first_execution = FALSE;
    if (mBox->nMessages > 0 &&
        mBox->pHead->Status == RECEIVER) { // receiving task is waiting
      ...
    } else {
      msg *m = safe_malloc(sizeof(msg));
      m->pData = safe_malloc(mBox->nDataSize); 
      memcpy(m->pData, pData, mBox->nDataSize); // copy data to the message
      m->Status = SENDER;
      listobj *node = list_get_head(ready_list);
      m->pBlock = node;
      node->pMessage = m;
      mailbox_push_no_wait_msg(mBox, m);
      // ASYNCHRONOUS, DON'T RESCHEDULE HERE
    }
  }
  return OK;
}

void *safe_malloc(unsigned int size) {
  void *mem = malloc(size);
  mem_counter++;
  return mem;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't where you think it is? Could it be a problem with `malloc` it self? Did you write it? Or it is you writing out of bounds somewhere else leading to a problem here?

Comment: I use the `malloc` in the standard library, yes I am trying to test the rest of code...

Comment: This function looks fishy: `SaveContext();` Is it doing what its name implies? Do you mess with your stack frame? When is `send_no_wait` called? Is it in some interrupt context?

Comment: Does your function `isr_off` allow for nested calling? When are interrupts enabled again?

Comment: I believe that `SaveContext()` works fine, and I have not implemented `isr_on` and `isr_off`, they just defined as `{}`.

Comment: `volatile uint first_execution = TRUE;` is *always* going to set `first_execution` to `TRUE` on every call to `send_no_wait()`.

Comment: `volatile uint first_execution = TRUE;`Do you really mean `volatile` or maybe `static`?

Comment: If `isr_off` is empty, you should remove it for a miminal example. It's not relevant and distracting.

Comment: Perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) could work on your system

Comment: Yes, I mean need volatile in this function, every time it gets called, it must be TRUE, I have another function `LoadContext` to jump back to the next instruction after `SaveContext`, this variable is to distinguish if it is the first execution or not, and I have removed the interrupt relevant code. @Gerhardh

Comment: Insure this is not a trivial problem by declaring `safe_malloc()` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is with `memcpy(m->pData, pData, mBox->nDataSize);` as it follows `shallow copy` concept. Try to replace with a `deep copy` concept.